# How to use Google Maps API to render the map of a particular location with 1) traffic data overlay on roads 2) name labels removed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

The following screen grab below is what I would like it to look like ( except for the place names and building name labels removed ). I would like the road names to stay on.

[image: the map screen grab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Styling" to hide Map features. Also, the Maps Styling Wizard is very useful for this : 
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Styling :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: 40.707165, lng: -73.947074},
    styles: [
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  }
]
  });
```

And you can use the "TrafficLayer" to show traffic in you JavaScript Map :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic

TrafficLayer:

```
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Here is a sample fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xkcpL85h/

Screenshot of fiddle Output
[image]